# Best possible to approach to save cassandra data to s3 using spark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, cassandra, parquet, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a cassandra table which size is ~150 GB. I want to migrate the table to a different cassandra cluster. I have two approaches here :-
1. Using spark job to read data from the old cluster and write to the new cluster.
2. Save the cassandra data to S3 using some format . Once the data is saved to S3 read it again using spark to save the data to the new cluster.
   If i go with this approach then what format should i save the data ? Because i have to again read the data from S3. So, which format will be best in this case ? csv or json or parquet ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using COPY TO command to extract in csv, then copy data back in - https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshCopy.html

e.g.

```
COPY my_table TO 'my_table.csv' // on source Cassandra
COPY my_table FROM 'my_table.csv' // on destination Cassandra
```